# Don't use .clear to clear your List

Tags: java, list, hashset

I need to sort and remove duplicates from a List that is being passed into my method. However, I am not supposed to use the .clear on my List so I am not sure how to get my list to only have what my hashSet has in it.

```
public static void sortAndRemoveDups(List<Integer>listToFix)
{
    Set<Integer> listToFix1 = new HashSet<>(listToFix);
    listToFix.clear();
    listToFix.addAll(listToFix1);
    System.out.println(listToFix);
}
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to order the list and remove duplicates without resorting to a hashset.

Comment: How about creating a new ArrayList from the HashSet.

Comment: actually one of the requirements is to use a set as part of our solution.

Comment: Are you just barred from using `clear()` specifically, or is this a more general prohibition against clearing the `List`?  You can always just iterate through the list and `remove()` all the elements manually.

Comment: another requirement is to be modifying the original lists contents.

Comment: The list is never allowed to be cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic way to go about it would be:

```
public static void sortAndRemoveDups(List<Integer>listToFix)
{
    Set<Integer> listToFix1 = new HashSet<>(listToFix);
    for(Integer i : listToFix1){
        listToFix.removeAll(i);
        listToFix.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(listToFix);
}
```

PS: If you have any more requirements, why not add it to OP.

Comment: Sorry, I will make sure I add all requirements at start next time.